# How can i test this button click event in angular?

Tags: angular

```
<button type="button" class="btn" (click)="call()">Click me!!</button>
```

i have this button as part of component.html

```
call(): void {
    console.log('button clicked!!');
  }
```

and this as part of component.ts

I tried spying on the **call** method and initiated a click event by extracting the button but it seems the function isn't getting covered. something like this

```
  it('onBtnClick_ShouldLogTheOutput', () => {
    // Arrange
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const spy = spyOn(app, 'call');
    const btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.btn'));
    // Act
    btn.nativeElement.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // Assert
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I even tried looking into other stack overflow answers and some suggested doing it using fakeAsync and tick i replicated it too but ain't working...

Can anyone help me with mistakes am i doing / corrections i need to make in order to make it work?

Comment: Are there any errors being produced in the console or is the test simply failing?

Comment: No errors being thrown, but the function "call" isn't getting covered as part of code coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `call()` method isn't showing up in your code coverage because it's not getting covered. You're mocking it with `spyOn()`. The spy will track calls to the method but it won't run the method implementation, so the code isn't covered. You can change your spy to `spyOn(app, 'call').and.callThrough()`. This will allow you to track calls to the method while still running the method itself.